# how to span multiple columns in a multi-column linkki section

Tags: java, css, vaadin, linkki

What is the best way to create a multi-column layout in [**linkki**](https://github.com/linkki-framework/linkki) with a field spanning multiple columns?

```
| Label1: Field1(quite long)       |
| Label2: Field2 | Label3: Field3 |
```

1. CustomLayoutSection - I would like to avoid that for such a simple(?) case
2. SectionLayout.COLUMN, add a blank Label after Label1, use CSS to make Field1 cover it (how?)
3. maybe add some kind of colSpan-aspect?
4. Use multiple Sections - I'd like to avoid that

Comment: What is linkki? GridLayout has colspan functionality

Comment: @AndréSchild https://github.com/linkki-framework/linkki

Comment: Use a CssLayout and you can pretty much use whatever CSS you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there are only very basic layout possibilities for @UISection.

(1)
Instead of a [CustomLayout](http://doc.linkki-framework.org/linkki-1.0-SNAPSHOT/05_ui_components/01_layout.html#_column_layout) you could create your layout with standard vaadin components and use [@Bind](http://doc.linkki-framework.org/linkki-1.0-SNAPSHOT/04_creating_a_ui/03_manual_binding_with_bind.html) to setup the linkki binding.

(2)
I do not suggest to use `@UISection` with `SectionLayout.COLUMN` because it would be very tricky to calculate the necessary size of your component Field1 in CSS. The layout consists of multiple `<div>` and in CSS you do not know anything about the size of the other columns.

(3)
A custom [apect](http://doc.linkki-framework.org/linkki-1.0-SNAPSHOT/08_aspects/99_creating_a_new_aspect.html) will not help because it is designed to change the properties of a component not the layout within it's parent. The colspan in vaadin need to be specified while adding the component to its parent.

(4)
Of course you could use two sections, the second without a section header but this may lead to different sizes of the first label column.

In future version of linkki we will provide some additional functionality to create custom layouts using annotations. Then you could write your own layout annotation and specify such a layout for your own. We know that you will get only 80% of your layout using the standard `@UISection` layout. But with this approach these 80% getting as easy as possible and still the remaining 20% is easily done using a custom layout.

Comment: I ended up with your solution (4), synchronizing the first column's labels' widths of the two sections.

Answer (score 1):

Linkki now allows for easier declaration of [nested components](https://doc.linkki-framework.org/latest/05_ui_components/06_nested_components.html), i.e. the functionality mentioned by @cornz Using this, a nested component with the desired layout should be fairly easy, perhaps a @UIHorizontalLayout annotated section